# How to load an image from PHP to a flash movieclip?

Tags: php, image, actionscript, movieclip

First of all, let me say that I have no actionscript knowledge, but I have PHP knowledge.

How can I make a movieclip display an image from a php file?

And how can I send the image from the php file to the movieclip?

Do I echo it?

Comment: You are asking two questions, please ask one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, i know you could have just used the googles to look this up, but I'm gonna explain how to do it anyway.

> How can I make a movieclip display an image from a php file?

```
<?php

// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './img/ok.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

This code was copy-pasta'd from the [php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php). In short you should use `fpassthru`

> How can I send the image from the php file to the movieclip?

Use the [`Loader` class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/). An example is at the bottom of the page.